# A specifc Regular expression in XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt

My doubt is very specific:

Whats the meaning of this regex in XSLT:

```
"replace(concat('1-',replace($contentSep[1],'\.','-')),'-0(\d+)','-$1')"
```

My '**$contentSep[1]**' is something like: '01.01.01'.

My main doubt is in the meaning of '-0(\d+)' and '-$1'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace($contentSep[1],'\.','-')` makes the input: `01-01-01`

`concat('1-', ...)` makes the transformed input: `1-01-01-01`

finally the `replace('...', '-0(\d+)','-$1')` making the transformed  input into : `1-1-1-1`. So this is basically removing the `0` before a number(`\d`).

Comment: Thanks, but tell me what's the meaning of the '$' in the last field? Is it referring to the number 1, or any variable?

Comment: `$1` is the captured group that was matched from replacing regex. In your case `$1` holds the value of `(\d+)`